# responsiveness is not working for the forgot password link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have designed login page using bootstrap 3 template. I have to place a  forgot password link right end to remember me checkbox, but when i resize the browser the forgot password link are displaced i mean forgot password link coming second row How to avoid this

Fiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/tgmorswx/5/

Expected Result : [image]

```
.vertical-offset-100{
    padding-top:100px;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row vertical-offset-100">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
         <div class="alert alert-success">
   Incorrect username or password.
  </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="text">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label>
                                <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me"> Remember Me
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap

Comment: You can give `padding-top: 15px` manually to the `.container`

Comment: Bootstrap 4.0 has some [spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) which you can use. I do not know for sure whether this is supported in BS3.

Comment: tell us please bs3 or bs4??

Comment: i am using bootstrap 3

Comment: people are posting whatever coming to their mind they are not gining heed to the problem statement

Answer (score 1):

**remove this:**

```
.login-panel {
    margin-top: 25%; 
}
```

**by:** (see fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/8f4epsqh/)

```css
.login-panel{
   margin-top: 15px!important;}
.alert-danger{
  margin-top: 15px!important;
}
```

```html
                      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade in">
             <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
             <strong>Danger!</strong> This alert box could indicate a dangerous or potentially negative action.
               </div>
                 <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                    <form role="form">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="email" autofocus>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form -->
                                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

you can set `margin-top` to alert(as i did)

Comment: I have tried this what happens is when i do margin-top is 0 both error alert and the panel are shifted to top of the browser that shouldn't happen

Comment: when i remove alert modal, login panel shifted top of the browser

Comment: see my edit `.login-panel{
   margin-top: 15px!important;}`

Comment: tell me if it helps!

Comment: No I am not getting proper output

Comment: check your bs3 script please

Answer (score 1):

Check This One

https://jsfiddle.net/F86597/pq4ncrb7/1/

```
.alert-danger{
  margin-top: -85px!important;
  position: absolute;
}
.login-panel{
   margin-top: 100px!important;
}
```

Comment: this is okay but the width of the alert increasing and decreasing based on text content that should not be

Comment: add `width:94%` to `alert` New jsfiddle  http://www.jsfiddle.net/pq4ncrb7/2  @smithagowda

Comment: your answer is perfect but isn't possible without giving margin-top values in other way

Comment: How to put forgot password link

Comment: Test this for responsiveness https://github.com/login click submit without credential and resize the browser

Comment: look at below one??

Comment: @smithagowda  I can't understand what you want to say?  Keep your question clear

Answer (score 0):

Guys i got a better solution for my above question, you can resize the browser no problem

```css
.vertical-offset-100{
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row vertical-offset-100">
     <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
   <div class="alert alert-success">
   Incorrect username or password.
  </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
     </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
                    <fieldset>
           <div class="form-group">
             <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="text">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
         </div>
         <div class="checkbox">
             <label>
              <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me"> Remember Me
             </label>
            </div>
      
         <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
        </fieldset>
          </form>
       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

heres is the code for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="author" content="Vojtěch Matras">
  <title>Admin Express Blogs&Magazines</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>


    <div class="container">
      <div class="row vertical-offset-100">
          <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
           <div class="alert alert-success">
     Incorrect username or password.
    </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h3 class="panel-title">Please sign in</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      <form accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
                      <fieldset>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email" type="text">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                              <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                          </div>
                          <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-6">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                  <label>
                                      <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me"> Remember Me
                                  </label>
                              </div>

                              </div>
                              <div class="col-6">
                                <div>
                                  <a href="#" >Forgot password??</a>
                                </div>

                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Login">
                      </fieldset>
                      </form>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

you can check fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ouuj70Ld/    resize the window to see responsiveness.